# FirebaseRemoteConfigFetchException

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I have this non-fatal exception in fabric:

```
com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigFetchException: Fetch failed due to an unexpected error! Check logs for details.
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzer.zzc(zzer.java:80)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzer.zzb(zzer.java:23)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzer.zza(zzer.java:149)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zzes.then(zzes.java)
   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(zzf.java:2)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

I can't reproduce it. 
I have cache time in remote config fetch 0.

I call fetch in two cases:

1. My own cache expire (12h) user launch app and I call fetch.
2. I edit remote config in firebase console, automatically push to device that remote config is changed and I call fetch immediately.

And there is no log, where I can find these logs?

Comment: Its just non-fatal exception. If you are using `mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();` then try to use new method `mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activate();`

Comment: I've also got this exception 139 times in the last week. I'm already using the new `activate()` method. I have no idea why is happening..